# Load report failed due to Failed to logon to the Crystal Report Object Repository

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

We are using SAP Integration KIT and Crystal Reports 2008. The Crystal Reports are being displayed on Winform (VB.net Windows application) (VS 2005 with net fx 2.0).

The development environment is 32bit, everything works fine. Reports are working with local BI server. The issue is in Production Server. Production server is of 64 bit.

1. Windows exe is complied to installed on any configuration.
2. "SAP Integration KIT and Crystal Reports 2008" are installed of 32 bit versions.
3. On opening of crystal reports this was giving following exception:

> Error: "An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions
>   are insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed
>   correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports
>   redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the
>   Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.

For this we changed the 32bit flag our exe to 32bit+ using corflag.exe tool. The above error was removed and a following new error occurs. We have checked permission of temp folder/report folder etc. and everything is fine. We are stuck here. A little help/guidance can save our weekend :).

> Type : CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException,
>   CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304 Message : Load report failed. Source :
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine Help link :  Data :
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal TargetSite : Void
>   EnsureDocumentIsOpened() Stack Trace :    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
>   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String
>   filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String
>   filename)    at BizzCare.frmReportViewer.frmReportViewer_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)

Additional Info:

> MachineName : xxx
>
> TimeStamp : 6/14/2012 7:50:15 AM
>
> FullName : 
>   Microsoft.PracticesEnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling,
>   Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>
> AppDomainName : abc.exe
>
> ThreadIdentity : admin
>
> WindowsIdentity : comp\user
>       Inner Exception
>       ---------------
>       Type : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>       Message :  Error in File Last12MonthsSales{9D0A761A-8021-42E6-8ECF-CE2C0167F5B0}.rpt: Failed to
>   logon to the Crystal Report Object Repository.
>       Source : Analysis Server
>       Help link : 
>       ErrorCode : -2147217397
>       Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>       TargetSite : Void Open(System.Object ByRef, Int32)
>       Stack Trace :    at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object&
>   DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
>          at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object&
>   DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
>          at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have resolved this issue.

There were runtime version difference, the reports were designed by using 12.1.xxx version of crystal reports (As SAP provides latest one for dev env) and Visual Studio 2008 provides 10.x.xx

version to be deployed as a part of setup. We have downloaded the 12.1.xxx version cr120_redist_install.zip and installed this on deployment server and works..

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to difference in runtime versions used in development environment and installed on production environment.

The confusion was because that the “Crystal Report 2008 SP1” installed by default with “SAP Integration Kit” has to be removed/uninstalled manually” (as this provides older versions’ DLLs) and then proper runtime has to be installed after manually downloading from Microsoft site.